# THREE.Js Emissive texture maps

Tags: dictionary, three.js, textures

Is it possible to use illumination maps, or emissive textures ? i have tried    "mapEmissive": "illumination_3.jpg", and    "colorEmissive" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], but cant seem to get it to work. I saw that their is a code implementation by Ekitson mentioned on github ....

my JSON files material properties: 
    "materials": [  {
    "shading":"Phong" ,
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "military_space_fighter_black3",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.588, 0.588, 0.588],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.588, 0.588, 0.588],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    "colorEmissive" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    "illumination" : 2,
    "mapAmbient" : "super_black_color_3.jpg",
    "mapBump" : "bump_3.jpg",
    "mapDiffuse" : "super_black_color_3.jpg",
    "mapEmissive": "illumination_3.jpg",
    "mapSpecular" : "specular_3.jpg",
    "opticalDensity" : 1.5,
    "specularCoef" : 10.0,
    "transparency" : 0.0
    }],

Answer (score 0):

In r55 there is no "mapEmissive" or "colorEmissive" attribute. If you look at the webgl_materials.html example you will see that there is an "emissive" property to the material.

Comment: that seems to be for one colour only. I'm looking to make an emissive texture map.